# Website opens in cp1251, charset is set to UTF8

Tags: html

This website: http://360rossia.com/ opens in cp1251 encoding. Any ideas why? It shouldn't, it has this in the head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your web server sends this in the response headers:

```
Content-Type:text/html; charset=windows-1251
```

it overrides the meta setting. You will need to configure your web server to output the correct character set.

Comment: I'm interested in how you saw what the web server was sending ?

Comment: @DreamWave Firebug's "Net" tab can show all the resources that get loaded in a page, and the response headers. In Chrome, the function is built-in, access it by clicking "inspect element" anywhere on the page and then switch to the "Network" tab. IE8 has this as well, but I don't remember where - press `F12` for the developer tools